# FABRIC_E_INVALID_ADDRESS when contacting service fabric stateless service through remote proxy

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am getting a "FABRIC_E_INVALID_ADDRESS" 400 Bad Request when contacting my stateless service externally.

I have set up the reverse proxy exactly as it says in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy

I am contacting the service the same way it explains to in the documentation, with:

```
http://clustername.com:19008/MyApp/MyService
```

I am fairly confident the reverse proxy is working as intended, because the port 19008 returns a response from service fabric. Also:

1. If I strip MyService from the URL, I get a 404 SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
2. If I change the service name, I get a 404 SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
3. If I use another port, I get a timeout.

So it sees that the service exists, but returns the invalid address 400 error.

Are there any sort of diagnostics I can leverage? The main issue with this problem is all I have to go on is 400 FABRIC_E_INVALID_ADDRESS, which produces no google results other than a list of error codes with no descriptions from MSDN. There is nothing else in the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but it begun to work when I added the UriScheme and Protocol attributes to the Endpoint in the ServiceManifest.xml Endpoints sections:

```
<Endpoint Name="Test1TypeEndpoint" UriScheme="http" Protocol="http" />
```

as I am deploying using Guest Containers, it will not work until you also add a Policiy in the ServiceManifestImport section of the ApplicationManifest.xml stating the port exposed by the docker container:

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Test1Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  <ConfigOverrides />
  <Policies>
    <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
      <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="Test1TypeEndpoint" />
    </ContainerHostPolicies>
  </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

The CodePackageRef attribute must match the CodePackage Name of the ServiceManifest.xml:

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
```